# Get custom records from Address locator service in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding

I've already created an **Address Locator** successfully and published it as a Geo coding service, but have some additional requirement.

Let's say I've a field in my data set named ***category*** which have different values like

- Houses
- Parks
- ATM

What I want is to pass this ***category*** value as parameter and get the service results from only those records which match the ***category*** parameter value.

I need to know how to make it happen?

Comment: It's possible to do that with custom locator styles, at least at the desktop level. What version of ArcGIS are you working with?

Comment: @EvilGenius we've all the versions of ArcGIS Desktop and Server 10.1, 10.2, 10.3
we need this functionality on arc gis server

Comment: @MDHald.. I read the link you provided and created a *Gazetter Geocoder* while setting the category attribute against Type parameter, but I don't know how to pass this parameter, would you please elaborate this a bit more?